# GRIDFS mp3 Collection with meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am new to meteor and I am trying to define an mp3 collection and then upload music to it from the admin page.
I have these packages installed: 
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:gridfs
cfs:filesystem
1)
I have defined the collection both on the client and the server but I dont see it show up in my RoboMongo, I dont know what I am missing

```
AudioCollection = new FS.Collection("audiocollection", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("audiocollection")]
});
```

2)
How do I handle my template event the music file uploaded by an admin and insert it into my AudioCollection.

```
Template.example_music.events({
  'click #example':function(e,t){
    //Simple Event to upload files into mongo.

  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to store my files in AWS and then save the url in mongoDB, so in my web application I request for the urls and load it in the browser. That does the magic and load my file comntents.

Answer (score 1):

Those packages are no longer supported. I would recommend using https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection . There are a couple of example projects to help you get going.

I use this myself and find it very good. It's also simpler to use than the collectionFS packages